# How to highlight each row after each preformed task

Tags: excel, vba

I made below script for Creation of PO's.
Input data is taken from excel sheet.

[image]

Now what code can be added so that after each PO is created which is equal to each row is performed the code highlights each row in green or adds a comment "Finished" in Column 5?

---

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize



REM ADDED BY EXCEL *************************************

Dim objExcel
Dim objSheet, intRow, i
Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 to objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
COL1 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)) 'Column1
COL2 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value)) 'Column2
COL3 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value)) 'Column3
COL4 = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value)) 'Column4

REM ADDED BY EXCEL *************************************

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nme21n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd    [0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-KONNR[29,0]").text = COL1
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[30,0]").text = COL2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[30,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-KTPNR[30,0]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0020/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-MENGE[6,0]").text = COL3
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0020/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-EEIND[9,0]").text = COL4
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0020/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-EEIND[9,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0020/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/ctxtMEPO1211-EEIND[9,0]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0020/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-MENGE[6,0]").text = COL3
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press



REM FINALIZATION CONTROL CHECK ************************

aux=col1 & " " & col2 & " " & col3 & " " & col4
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run("cmd /c @echo %date% %time% " & aux & " >> C:\SCRIPT\PlOrCreationLog.txt")
next

msgbox "Process Completed"

REM FINALIZATION CONTROL CHECK ************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something along these lines should do the trick?

```
objSheet.range(objSheet.Cells(i, 1),objSheet.Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
objSheet.Cells(i, 5) = "Finished"
```

Comment: Indeed it did. Thank you!